# Chip Holder for LM8560

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am building a digital alarm clock, and I need a chip holder for the LM8560 chip. I tried a sop 30 to dip 30 holder. The chip fits on width but not length. The chip is to long and even if I used sop 40 to dip 40 chip holder not all of the pins on the chip would align with the holes in the socket. I have tried making a chip holder by drilling holes in a piece of MDF, sitting the chip in those holes and soldering wire to the chip pins. However in the process I believe I damaged the chip and the circuit will not work properly. Could someone please recommend me a chip holder that would work, or a method of building one that would not require soldering anything to the chip pins? Or even a company who makes custom chip holders?

Comment: The only datasheet I could find for LM8560 show it being a sdip28 chip which means you need a sdip to dip adapter (sdip is a skinny dip which is thinner than dip, sop is a surface mount pkg which is thinner and shorter than dip). can find a 28 pin one here - http://www.epboard.com/eproducts/ezadapter.htm#Shrink%20DIP%20%28SDIP%29%20to%20DIP%20Adapter

Comment: Picture of your ic on the chip holder please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet I found show the LM8560 being a SDIP chip and not SOP. This means you need a SDIP to DIP adapter (sdip is a skinny dip which is thinner than dip, sop is a surface mount pkg which is thinner and shorter than dip).

I have used these guys before: http://www.epboard.com/eproducts/ezadapter.htm#Shrink%20DIP%20%28SDIP%29%20to%20DIP%20Adapter

They have a SDIP to DIP 28 pin adapter if that's what you require. They also do custom adapters where you can give them the specs and they make the adapter for you.

Comment: Thanks that link was really useful I might end up using a chip holder from there

Answer (score 1):

Try using swiss machine pin headers.

[image: Machine Pin Headers]

If the pitch doesn't match the pitch on your chip, you could look at making a custom little PCB socket to convert to a more useful pitch too.

Comment: That's interesting the chip holder I purchased used those with a custom PCB setup, so I can recycle the machine pin headers off that

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.electronics.components/2006-07/msg00037.html) almost-10-year-old post from a usually reliable source, production SDIP sockets (1.778mm pitch) are (or were) available from Assman and test sockets from Yamaichi.

Mouser currently has 28-pin ZIF 1.778mm pitch sockets from 3M in stock 228-1290-00-0602J and, as usual, they're quite expensive.

Also, for an intermediate cost (machined pin rather than stamped), currently, Mill-Max and Precidip have 1.778mm pitch 28-pin sockets for about $5 each in singles. For example, [this one](http://www.mill-max.com/assets/pdfs/125.PDF) P/N 117-93-628-41-005000 from Mill-Max.